# Partial Plot can't be produced from randomForest in R

Tags: r, random-forest

The model is constructed and all the variable importance plots can be produced. However, when I used `partialPlot` on continuous variable, for example `purchase_value`:
`partialPlot(rf, fraud_data_train, purchase_value, which.class = 1)`
the error is

```
Error in is.finite(x): default method not implemented for type 'list'
```

For the categorical variable(`browser`) the error is 
`partialPlot(rf, fraud_data_train, browser, which.class = 1)`

```
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : 
  only defined on a data frame with all numeric variables
```

The data is available [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/o7f91fb9hs1cchl/data.rda?dl=0) and the code is as below:

```
rf = randomForest(y = fraud_data_train$class_factor, 
                  x = fraud_data_train[,-predictors_notinclude],
                  ntree = 30, mtry = 4, keep.forest = TRUE,
                  importance = TRUE, proximity = TRUE)
partialPlot(rf, fraud_data_train, purchase_value, which.class =1)
```

**Update:**

Here is the screenshot from my R studio console:
[image]

**Update 2**

Somehow the plot showed up in the notebook markdown..but still confused why it can't be output in the console
[image]

Comment: I can't reproduced either error - they both work fine for me with `randomForest_4.6-12`. Is `partialPlot` being masked? Try `randomForest::partialPlot(rf, fraud_data_train, purchase_value, which.class = 1)`.

Comment: Thanks @jbaums I tried again but still got the error. I am using the `randomForest 4.6-12` as well. I am not sure which part is broken. I tried it on different machine as well. My system is Win 10.

Comment: You can try debugging the function to find out where the problem is: `debugonce(randomForest::partialPlot); partialPlot(rf, fraud_data_train, purchase_value, which.class =1)`. When you see `UseMethod("partialPlot")`, step into that function with `s`. See `?browser` for more commands. If using RStudio, you can use the debugging buttons above the console.

Comment: Thanks!! The debugging does not work somehow but i accidentally clicked `notebook` button in R studio and the plot magically showed up (see update 2)...

Answer (score 16):

If your data is not in the form of a dataframe this will cause [partialplot()](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/randomForest/versions/4.6-14/topics/partialPlot) to throw that error. Looking at the documentation for `partialplot()` it states that the data must be in the form of a dataframe:

> pred.data
> a data frame used for constructing the plot, usually the
> training data used to construct the random forest..

You can fix this by coercing the data to be a dataframe for example by using `as.data.frame()`

Here is an example using your data: `partialPlot(rf, as.data.frame(fraud_data_train), purchase_value, which.class = 1)`.

Comment: That's what worked for me too.
`partialPlot(rf,  data.frame(train),  var_name, class_name)`